# Why does JPA give me a syntax error at or near?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am learning spring-boot and I have a connection to a database, I am trying to perform the following query.

```
@Query(value = "select f.entity_id as 'NIT' from renting.fine f where f.companyparent = :companyParent", nativeQuery = true)
```

But it generates the following error about the value that starts with a single quote, I can't get it to recognize the value

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'NIT'"
```

Comment: `'NIT'` - single quotes in SQL denote string literal, If you want to define column alias you either need to use double quotes  or do not use quotes at all. Comma before `from` will also cause syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes around 'NIT'. In order to define aliases for column you don't require quotes at all.

```
@Query(value = "select f.entity_id as NIT from renting.fine f where f.companyparent = :companyParent", nativeQuery = true)
```

This should work.